# keyring.get_password() throws NameError when reading credential from Windows Credential Manager

Tags: python, windows, keyring

I am try to implement keyring on a windows system to manage database passwords for connection strings in pyodbc and sqlalchemy. I have tried to ensure the relevant packages from the NameError(s) thrown are installed.

[Reason for manually setting the backend in keyring on windows](https://github.com/jaraco/keyring/issues/324)

Here is the code I ran:`

```
from keyring.backends import Windows
import keyring
keyring.set_keyring(Windows.WinVaultKeyring())
keyring.get_password("Service", "Username")
```

Here are the errors thrown:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\Python310\lib\site-packages\keyring\backends\Windows.py", line 109, in _get_password
    res = win32cred.CredRead(
NameError: name 'win32cred' is not defined

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File ".\Python310\lib\site-packages\keyring\core.py", line 55, in get_password
    return get_keyring().get_password(service_name, username)
  File ".\Python310\lib\site-packages\keyring\backends\Windows.py", line 99, in get_password
    res = self._get_password(service)
  File ".\Python310lib\site-packages\keyring\backends\Windows.py", line 112, in _get_password
    except pywintypes.error as e:
NameError: name 'pywintypes' is not defined
```

Installed packages are listed:

| Package | Version |
| --- | --- |
| astroid | 2.9.3 |
| backcall | 0.2.0 |
| certifi | 2021.10.8 |
| cffi | 1.15.0 |
| charset-normalizer | 2.0.12 |
| cloudpickle | 2.1.0 |
| colorama | 0.4.4 |
| comtypes | 1.1.11 |
| cryptography | 37.0.2 |
| dask | 2022.6.1 |
| executing | 0.8.3 |
| fsspec | 2022.5.0 |
| greenlet | 1.1.2 |
| idna | 3.3 |
| ipython-genutils | 0.2.0 |
| isort | 5.10.1 |
| keyring | 23.6.0 |
| lazy-object-proxy | 1.7.1 |
| locket | 1.0.0 |
| mccabe | 0.6.1 |
| mistune | 0.8.4 |
| MouseInfo | 0.1.3 |
| numpy | 1.22.3 |
| opencv-python | 4.5.5.64 |
| packaging | 21.3 |
| pandas | 1.4.1 |
| partd | 1.2.0 |
| pickleshare | 0.7.5 |
| Pillow | 9.1.1 |
| pip | 22.1.2 |
| platformdirs | 2.5.1 |
| pure-eval | 0.2.2 |
| PyAutoGUI | 0.9.53 |
| pycparser | 2.21 |
| PyGetWindow | 0.0.9 |
| pylint | 2.12.2 |
| PyMsgBox | 1.0.9 |
| pyodbc | 4.0.32 |
| pyparsing | 3.0.7 |
| pyperclip | 1.8.2 |
| PyQt6 | 6.3.1 |
| PyQt6-Qt6 | 6.3.1 |
| PyQt6-sip | 13.4.0 |
| PyRect | 0.2.0 |
| PyScreeze | 0.1.28 |
| pytesseract | 0.3.9 |
| python-bidi | 0.4.2 |
| python-dateutil | 2.8.2 |
| pytweening | 1.0.4 |
| pytz | 2022.1 |
| PyWavelets | 1.3.0 |
| pywin32 | 303 |
| pywin32-ctypes | 0.2.0 |
| pywinauto | 0.6.8 |
| PyYAML | 6 |
| requests | 2.27.1 |
| scipy | 1.8.0 |
| Send2Trash | 1.8.0 |
| setuptools | 58.1.0 |
| six | 1.16.0 |
| SQLAlchemy | 1.4.39 |
| sudo | 1.0.0 |
| tifffile | 2022.3.16 |
| toml | 0.10.2 |
| toolz | 0.11.2 |
| torch | 1.11.0 |
| torchaudio | 0.11.0 |
| torchvision | 0.12.0 |
| traitlets | 5.1.1 |
| typing_extensions | 4.1.1 |
| urllib3 | 1.26.9 |
| wcwidth | 0.2.5 |
| webencodings | 0.5.1 |
| wrapt | 1.13.3 |

Comment: Looks like the code in Windows.py method'_get_password' needs to know the constant: 'code'win32cred.CRED_TYPE_GENERIC'code' (=1) and see the class 'pywintypes.error'. I can access both in my python shell after imports. I am not sure why this would throw an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was an issue with extra python installations on my device.

I fixed this issue by deleting an extra set of python installations on my computer.

[Create venv without admin access python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72903927/create-venv-without-admin-access-python)

```
import keyring
keyring.set_keyring(Windows.WinVaultKeyring())
keyring.get_password("Service", "Username")
keyring.set_password("TestService","TestUser", "TestPassword")
keyring.get_password("TestService", "TestUser")
```

Prints:

```
'TestPassword'
```

Edit, this also fixes the need to set the default keyring.
I can omit: `keyring.set_keyring(Windows.WinVaultKeyring())`