# Create venv without admin access python

Tags: python, windows, python-venv

When I run python `-m venv \pathtomyvenv`

`Error: Command '['C:\\Users\\user\\manageSQL\\Scripts\\python.exe', '-Im', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default-pip']' returned non-zero exit status 1.`

A similar post cites a Windows update as the culprit.
[Fix by installing launcher for all users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69594088/error-when-creating-venv-error-command-im-ensurepip-upgrade-def)

Here is what the venv looks like after exit:

```
Include

Lib
    site-packages
Scripts
    python.exe
    pythonw.exe
pyvenv.cfg
    home = C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310
    include-system-site-packages = false
    version = 3.10.4
```

I cannot install python with admin privilege's in my environment. Is there another fix for this?

Comment: download python in your system in a seperate folder, and use that python to run the programs, not system one

Comment: I tried using a copy of python.exe copied to the desktop and got the same issue. Is that what you meant? (DesktopPath\python.exe) -m venv test4. As a side question, is this an issue with pip?

Comment: nope, priviliages to change things in AppData folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manually deleted all the python on my system that my privileges would allow. I could not delete the Python folder in:

`C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python` but did delete another python installation outside of AppData.

The removed python folder was in: `C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs`

**I can now create the venv and resolved an issue with importing a key library (dask).**

I believe the duplicate python installation was confusing the launcher but I cannot be sure.